# JupyterLab TensorFlow 2.3 Build Failed with 524

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, build-error

I created a new notebook in Google Cloud Vertex-AI that has the following properties:[image]

When I open the notebook, I am prompted by the following message:
[image]

After some time, I get the following error message:

```
Build failed with 524.

    If you are experiencing the build failure after installing an extension (or trying to include previously installed extension after updating JupyterLab) please check the extension repository for new installation instructions as many extensions migrated to the prebuilt extensions system which no longer requires rebuilding JupyterLab (but uses a different installation procedure, typically involving a package manager such as 'pip' or 'conda').

    If you specifically intended to install a source extension, please run 'jupyter lab build' on the server for full output.
```

When I run jupyter lab build in the terminal, I get:

```
    [LabBuildApp] WARNING | Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `LabBuildApp`.
[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 3.2.8
[LabBuildApp] Building in /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
Build failed.
Troubleshooting: If the build failed due to an out-of-memory error, you
may be able to fix it by disabling the `dev_build` and/or `minimize` options.

If you are building via the `jupyter lab build` command, you can disable
these options like so:

jupyter lab build --dev-build=False --minimize=False

You can also disable these options for all JupyterLab builds by adding these
lines to a Jupyter config file named `jupyter_config.py`:

c.LabBuildApp.minimize = False
c.LabBuildApp.dev_build = False

If you don't already have a `jupyter_config.py` file, you can create one by
adding a blank file of that name to any of the Jupyter config directories.
The config directories can be listed by running:

jupyter --paths

Explanation:

- `dev-build`: This option controls whether a `dev` or a more streamlined
`production` build is used. This option will default to `False` (i.e., the
`production` build) for most users. However, if you have any labextensions
installed from local files, this option will instead default to `True`.
Explicitly setting `dev-build` to `False` will ensure that the `production`
build is used in all circumstances.

- `minimize`: This option controls whether your JS bundle is minified
during the Webpack build, which helps to improve JupyterLab's overall
performance. However, the minifier plugin used by Webpack is very memory
intensive, so turning it off may help the build finish successfully in
low-memory environments.

An error occurred.
RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build
See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-ke3s6jt2.log
(base) jupyter@lookalike-conversion-model2:~$
```

When I check the log for this I get the following error (full error at bottom of post):

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I want to now how I can fix this error to achieve a successful build? I think this is what is leading to issues later on when I run my pipeline since I get this error once the model has finished training:

```
2022-02-24T13:15:54.660529854ZERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full log stack trace:

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v12.22.6

[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
[LabBuildApp] > node /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.89s.

[LabBuildApp] > node /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js yarn-deduplicate -s fewer --fail
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.21.1
$ /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/.bin/yarn-deduplicate -s fewer --fail
Done in 1.53s.

[LabBuildApp] > node /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js run build:prod:minimize
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.21.1
$ webpack --config webpack.prod.minimize.config.js

<--- Last few GCs --->

[17013:0x55b0f665b100]   203434 ms: Mark-sweep 2025.5 (2051.4) -> 2024.2 (2051.4) MB, 1531.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.079, current mu = 0.009) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[17013:0x55b0f665b100]   205286 ms: Mark-sweep 2028.4 (2054.3) -> 2025.7 (2052.1) MB, 1842.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.040, current mu = 0.005) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x12edd074a8d9]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x12edd0708ad2]
    2: StubFrame [pc: 0x12edd07bae96]
Security context: 0x18eab2cb2ec9 <JSObject>
    3: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x1766605ff901] [/opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/applySourceMap.js:156] [bytecode=0x1766605fa259 offset=503](this=0x1ea94dc00451 <undefined>,0x1dcd32299611 <String[2]: e.>,0x0b62ae...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x55b0f3faff69 node::Abort() [webpack]
 2: 0x55b0f3ee7b87 std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > node::SPrintFImpl<char const*>(char const*, char const*&&) [webpack]
 3: 0x55b0f41390b2 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [webpack]
 4: 0x55b0f413938b v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [webpack]
 5: 0x55b0f42ccf96  [webpack]
 6: 0x55b0f42df8ea v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [webpack]
 7: 0x55b0f42e05f4 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [webpack]
 8: 0x55b0f42e27ed v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [webpack]
 9: 0x55b0f42e2855 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [webpack]
10: 0x55b0f42a8fde v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Map, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [webpack]
11: 0x55b0f42b1770 v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [webpack]
12: 0x55b0f44f2011 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [webpack]
13: 0x55b0f44cd0ca v8::internal::StringTable::LookupString(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [webpack]
14: 0x55b0f45ea563 v8::internal::Runtime_HasProperty(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [webpack]
15: 0x12edd074a8d9 
Aborted
error Command failed with exit code 134.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab failed to build
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/debuglog.py", line 48, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 176, in start
    raise e

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 173, in start
    app_options=app_options, production = production, minimize=self.minimize)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 483, in build
    production=production, minimize=minimize, clean_staging=clean_staging)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 695, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question and to be use as a workaround, you should using the following command (as show on [the error commit about this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/pull/231/commits/4ec5b12698b30c8a9e05dc5c07c86de375bf5143)):

```
sudo -i
jupyter lab build --dev-build=False --minimize=False
jupyter labextension  list
```

Regardless, I have open an issue tracker with this case, you can check it on this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221802609) please upvote the question on it and lets wait for google devs official response.

Also, if you want additional details you can check I see a list of similar cases that I found which makes me think its an ongoing issue, related to network/image and its being look at the moment (partially), thats why I also open a issue tracker on google.

- [Error jupyter 524](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=notebook%20524)
- [Update Dockerfile to remove build warning](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/pull/231)
- [Jupyterlab too slow to load on slow networks](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3561#issuecomment-517673508)
- [Opening a notebook results in a 524 (A Timeout Occurred) error](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_524_a_timeout_occurred_error)

Comment: Hello @scott lucas, did this assist you on your question?

Comment: Hi @Betjens, yes this has helped thank you! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction to ask questions about my problem

Comment: if so, please upvote the question or add additional details into the issuetracker case created.

Comment: Also, I provide a workaround for your issue.